# CentOS6 Dedicated Server Mobile Management?

Tags: centos, centos6, mobile-devices

I am running a dedicated server on CentOS 6 and I need some mobile management, restart apache etc, monitor swap usage.

Is there anything on the market I can use to monitor this?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SSH client for your mobile device... :) That's what I do.

or something like the [Webmin theme for mobile](http://www.webmin.com/mobile.html).

Do you need graphing?